# What does __inline__ mean ?

Tags: c, inline

I am trying to learn C. Reading through some code, I came across a line like this:

```
__inline__ void () ...
```

What does the `__inline__` mean?. How does putting that word in front of a function make it different?

Comment: AWESOME question.  (Enough people complain about dumb questions that I wanted you to know.)  It's very specific, it can be answered directly, and it's very programming-related.

Comment: For low values of awe. It's a reasonable question, nothing more.

Comment: @ggg: please mark one of the excellent responses below as the answer to the question? Why? 1. this question continues to show up in queries for unanswered questions 2: the volunteers that answered your question deserve credit for their work.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`__inline__` is a *non-standard* extension. Typically, it tells the compiler: "inline this function", but being a non-standard extension we can't say with certainty unless we know which compiler this is on.

To inline is to remove the function call and place it's contents directly where the call would be made. This often removes the overhead of calling a function. It is not always optimal, because of code bloat (code getting too big and not fitting into cache), so most compilers will ignore all inline directives and do what they feel is best. *This is a good thing.* We humans are very poor at that kind of stuff, and it's usually considered bad practice to tell the compiler how to do its job.

Inlining is an important optimization, especially with the presence of helper functions. Imagine a function that returned the smaller of two ints:

```
int min(int x, int y)
{
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}
```

If I used this function in my code, it would be an enormous waste of time to actually make a function call, here. If I had:

```
int a = /* some calculation */;
int b = /* some other calculation */;

int minCalc = min(a, b);
```

And the compiler inlined that function, the code would become:

```
int a = /* some calculation */;
int b = /* some other calculation */;

int minCalc = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

Which removes the overhead of calling a function. From here, even more optimizations can be made as the compiler gets to work directly with the code that would have normally been hidden behind a function call. As you can see, if I have a big function and I force the compiler to inline it everywhere, the code size could grow *very* large very fast, and would actually hinder execution speed.

There is a standard `inline` keyword which was used to indicate to the compiler a function should be inlined, but nowadays most compilers don't even acknowledge it as a hint to inline the function.

There is an important side-effect of `inline`, though, and this can be useful. If a function is marked as `inline`, multiple definitions of the same function across multiple translation units is not an error. Instead, a single function definition is selected and the others are thrown out, and assumed to be the same (it's up to you to make sure this is *actually* okay!). This allows you to define a function within a header file without risking ODR violation errors.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure C99 has an "inline" keyword, just as C++ does.

Answer (score 8):

Inline is a suggestion to the compiler to inline the function - instead of generating a block of code for the function and `call` instructions wherever it's used, it effectively cut-and-pastes the generated code wherever that function is called.

It's typically only a suggestion - while it can increase performance if it's called in a tight loop, it typically increases memory usage which can have generally negative performance effects. The compiler will make up its own mind whether to inline a function or not - it might take "the programmer suggests inlining this" into account, but (on most compilers), simply declaring a function as inline doesn't guarantee it will be.

Comment: +1 for correctly noting that inline is a suggestion, at times the compiler may ignore it : http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.1

Answer (score 6):

[Wikipedia / Inline Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function)

> In [computer science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science), an **inline function** is a [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) construct used to tell a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) it should perform [in-line expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) on a particular function.  In other words, the compiler will insert the complete body of the function in every place in the code where that function is used.

[GCC Manual § 5.36](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Inline.html)

> If you are writing a header file to be included in ISO C89 programs, write `__inline__` instead of `inline`.  See [Alternate Keywords](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `__inline__` declaration tells the compiler that wherever the function will be called to "inline" the function instead.  Inlineing is similar to using a macro -- the code will be expanded out as if you had written it all right where you called the function.

See the [GNU docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

basically, it's a hint to the compiler; it's a suggestion that where this function is used it might be possible to insert the code directly.

the idea is that doing so could be more efficient, since it avoids the overhead of a function call; but, ultimately, the compiler uses a combination of code size, optimization options specified, and a little bit of voodoo to decide whether to *actually* respect this hint.

the voodoo bit is most confusing part. :) don't necessarily rely on `__inline__` (or the more standard inline) to work; optimize your algorithms or reorganize your code instead if you really care about speed.