# Merging code with C and Object with the __inline__ function in Gcc

Tags: object, gcc, inline

When I've read the gcc documentation I assumed that the inline (or **inline**) keyword would remove the function call overhead.

As I qoute:
"
One way GCC can achieve this is to integrate that function's code into the code for its callers.
This makes execution faster by eliminating the function-call overhead; in addition, if any of the actual argument values are constant, their known values may permit simplifications at compile time so that not all of the inline function's code needs to be included. 
" Gcc Manual 6.36

Thus I assumed that the following C code:

```
__inline__ int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}


int add_one(int a)
{
    return sum(a, 1);
}
```

would translate into

```
add_one:
    mov eax, [ebp-4]
    add eax, 0x01
    retn
```

Instead of:

```
add_one:
    push 0x01
    push [ebp-4]
    call sum
    retn
```

As this doesn't work how I expected I would like to ask a question.
I have an object file with a function. It exports the symbol _my_func. I got the C code with the following code:

```
extern __inline__ _my_func

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{    
    _my_func(argv[1]);
    _my_func(argv[2]);
}
```

How can I merge my object's code within my main function. Eg remove the call and the function overhead.

Thanks

Stolas

btw, even here ( [What does __inline__ mean ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082551/what-does-inline-mean) ) I noticed that it *should* remove the function overhead. But objdump says otherwise :S

Post Update:

Even with the following commands:

```
nasm -felf get42.s -o42.o
gcc O3 42.o main.c -o mybin.elf
objdump -d mybin.elf
```

I notice a little call like so:

```
<_get42>:
    xor eax, eax
    mov eax, 0x42
    ret

<main>:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    add esp, 0xfffffff0
    call _get42
    leave
    ret
```

btw I do notice it removed the (mov ebp, esp etc) overhead in the function. But is that all it does? As I just want to remove the call with the actual code within the function.. As in eliminate the call, jmp or push, ret.

Comment: What optimization settings are you using?

Comment: Default.
Compiling with:
nasm -f<win32 or elf> my_object -o someoutputobject.o
gcc -Wall someoutputobject.o some_c_code.c -o output.bin

Comment: What about telling GCC to do some optimizations? Like, at least, `-O1`?

Comment: Even with -o3 I see a little call being made. The -o3 can be found here http://pastebin.com/wxrfUJyd

Comment: It's `-Ox`, not `-oX`. Please update your post with the info (can't access pastebin from here).

Comment: Quickly tried it, still a `call` in there. However I need to read the entire documentation.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987020/can-the-linker-inline-functions  is what I am looking for indeed. Thanks, now I need to figure out  how to make the *.o with NASM and still allow lto